# Sort multiple text columns with NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, null, alphabetical

I have the following columns:

```
a    | null
x    | f
null | a
i    | n
```

I need both columns sorted alphabetically with nulls at the bottom, like so:

```
a    | a
i    | f
x    | n
null | null
```

Is there anyway to do this in mysql?

Comment: What is your mysql version?

Comment: Version - 8.0.18

Comment: https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-order-null-values-first-or-last-in-mysql
Your answer might be here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each column must be sorted independently from the other and then recombine the rows by the position of each value in that order.
With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select t1.col1, t2.col2
from (
  select col1, row_number() over(order by col1 is null, col1) rn
  from tablename
) t1 inner join (  
  select col2, row_number() over(order by col2 is null, col2) rn
  from tablename
) t2 on t2.rn = t1.rn
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vqQyKPZYiFp5rTzYQ3VdQP/0).
Or with CTEs:

```
with
  cte1 as (select col1, row_number() over(order by col1 is null, col1) rn from tablename),
  cte2 as (select col2, row_number() over(order by col2 is null, col2) rn from tablename)
select cte1.col1, cte2.col2
from cte1 inner join cte2 
on cte2.rn = cte1.rn
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vqQyKPZYiFp5rTzYQ3VdQP/1).
Results:

```
| col1 | col2 |
| ---- | ---- |
| a    | a    |
| i    | f    |
| x    | n    |
| null | null |
```

Answer (score 0):

To order the 2 columns independently, with nulls last?

For MySql 5.x, here's a solution that orders by π:

```
-- sample data
drop table if exists test;
create table test (col1 varchar(8), col2 varchar(8));
insert into test (col1, col2) values
('a', null), ('x', 'f'), (null, 'a'), ('i', 'n');

-- initiating variables
set @rn1:=0, @rn2:=0;
-- query that links on calculated rownumbers
select col1, col2
from (select @rn1:=@rn1+1 as rn, col1 from test order by coalesce(col1,'π') asc) q1
left join (select @rn2:=@rn2+1 as rn, col2 from test order by coalesce(col2,'π') asc) q2
  on q1.rn = q2.rn
order by q1.rn;
```

**Result:**

```
col1    col2
a       a
i       f
x       n
NULL    NULL
```

In MySql 8.0 the window function `ROW_NUMBER` can be used instead of variables.

```
select col1, col2
from (select row_number() over (order by coalesce(col1,'π') asc) as rn, col1 from test) q1
left join (select row_number() over (order by coalesce(col2,'π') asc) as rn, col2 from test where col2 is not null) q2
  on q1.rn = q2.rn
order by q1.rn;
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f4be40b0fe40a23dbdc8ffb1cf6c61b2)*